# How do I generate an array each line in textarea with AngularJS, and vice versa?

Tags: angularjs

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.delete = function(i){
        $scope.myArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
    $scope.myStr = 'aaaa\nbbbb\nccccc';
    $scope.$watch('myStr', function(myStr){
        $scope.myArray = myStr.split('\n');
        console.log('$scope.myArray', $scope.myArray);
    });
    $scope.$watch('myArray', function(e){
        if(e.length > 0){
            var string = '';
            for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
                if( e[i] !== ''){
                    string += e[i] + "\n";
                }
            }
            $scope.myStr = string;            
        }
    }, true);
}
```

I'm trying to create a `textarea` who's input is bound to an `array` where entries correspond to each line in the text.

And also every time an element is removed, the correspond text in `textarea` should be removed too.

How do I achieve that?
I'm trying to use $scope function `$watch`, but I'm having some issues when I'm typing the text in `textarea`, a single character is always generated.

Jsfiddle for a better look:
https://jsfiddle.net/pf4v83mb/

Comment: Could be worth investigating: https://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html  This pattern has saved me many painful `$watch`es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made one little mistake, when constructed string from array: added unnecessary `\n` to the end([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5pwa5pbb/1/)). That is why, when you type letter in textbox, blank new item (`\n`) is added to array and it forces textbox do the same, i.e. go to new line:

```
$scope.$watch('myArray', function(e){       
    if(e.length > 0){
        var string = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
            if( e[i] !== ''){
                //'\n' not needed for last element
                string += e[i] + (i == e.length - 1 ? '' : "\n");
            }
        }
        $scope.myStr = string;

    }
}, true);
```